# Visualizing part of the attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I have a shapefile with a long attribute table made of different columns. Some columns have several levels (es. `"Year": 2009, 2010, 2011,...` or `"Season": autumn, spring, summer, winter`) and other columns have just numerical values related to the environmental parameters (es. `"Temperature"`, `"humidity"`, etc).

I would like to display only values of Temperature in autumn, I have tried different expressions in `'Categorized'` or `'Rule-based'`, but without success. How can I make it?

Comment: Simply apply a filter `"Season"='autumn'` and then apply `Graduated` symbology

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok I can select with filter in the attribute table only rows corresponding to autumn, but then I would like to categorize only the values of temperature in autumn. I used: "Season" ='autumn' AND "Temperature" in the query builder of 'categorized' but it doesn't work.

Comment: I meant filter through `'Right click on the layer > Filter...'`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! It was easy!!